# Building Boost 1.46.1 *with openmpi*?

Tags: boost, openmpi

I would like to build all of the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) library on Ubuntu 11.04 with gcc 4.5.2.  So I went about downloading the tar.bz2 file.  I expanded it.  I ran bootstrap.sh and noticed it complaining about unicode, so I installed:

`sudo apt-get install libicu-dev`

And now it appears to be happily building with unicode.  The trouble is that I want to also link against OpenMPI.  uh oh.  So I add `using mpi ;` to `./tools/build/v2/user-config.jam` and ran my build command:

`./bjam --layout=versioned --build-type=complete`

And boost prints out errors(I've abbreviated the large paragraphs):

```
error: Duplicate name of actual target: <pstage/lib>mpi.so
error: previous virtual target { common%common.copy-mpi.so.PYTHON_EXTENSION {
```

... then a few pages  ...

```
error: created from ./stage-proper
error: another virtual target { common%common.copy-mpi.so.PYTHON_EXTENSION {
```

... then a few more pages ...

```
error: created from ./stage-proper
error: added properties: <debug-symbols>off <define>NDEBUG <inlining>full <library>object(file-target)@3501 <library>object(file-target)@3568 <library>object(file-target)@4171 <library>object(file-target)@4184 <library>object(searched-lib-target)@4066 <library>object(searched-lib-target)@4072 <library>object(searched-lib-target)@4078 <optimization>speed <runtime-debugging>off <variant>release <xdll-path>/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/mpi/build/gcc-4.5.2/release/threading-multi <xdll-path>/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.5.2/release/threading-multi <xdll-path>/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/gcc-4.5.2/release/threading-multi
error: removed properties: <debug-symbols>on <inlining>off <library>object(file-target)@1244 <library>object(file-target)@1350 <library>object(file-target)@2378 <library>object(file-target)@2393 <library>object(searched-lib-target)@2217 <library>object(searched-lib-target)@2223 <library>object(searched-lib-target)@2229 <optimization>off <runtime-debugging>on <variant>debug <xdll-path>/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/mpi/build/gcc-4.5.2/debug/threading-multi <xdll-path>/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/python/build/gcc-4.5.2/debug/threading-multi <xdll-path>/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/bin.v2/libs/serialization/build/gcc-4.5.2/debug/threading-multi
/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/tools/build/v2/build/virtual-target.jam:490: in actualize-no-scanner from module object(file-target)@4661
/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/tools/build/v2/build/virtual-target.jam:135: in object(file-target)@4661.actualize from module object(file-target)@4661
/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/tools/build/v2/build-system.jam:748: in load from module build-system
/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/tools/build/v2/kernel/modules.jam:283: in import from module modules
/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/tools/build/v2/kernel/bootstrap.jam:142: in boost-build from module
/home/mtibbits/src/boost_1_46_1/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope from module
```

It appears to be a [bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3560) dating back to Boost 1.40??  But I know others have gotten this to work.  Does anyone know the voodoo required to get Boost 1.46.1 to play nice with openmpi?

Note: I've been googling and this doesn't appear to be an Ubuntu specific problem -- it has appeared on [gentoo](https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=329207) and elsewhere.  But I haven't found any concrete solution except *build without mpi...* which I can't.

I would happily post the entire logs, package versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

from some other forum, I found that in /tools/build/CMake/externals, there should be a MPI.cmake file.
adding the following lines should allow you to build Boost with OpenMPI:

```
set(MPI_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/include/openmpi-x86_64)
set(MPI_COMPILE_FLAGS -I/usr/include/openmpi-x86_64)
set(MPI_LINK_FLAGS -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib -L/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/openmpi
-lmpi_cxx -lmpi)
set(MPI_LIBRARIES /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so
/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so)
set(MPI_FOUND 1)
```

Comment: I see from your answers you are a Cuda fan. What makes you interested to turning to OpenMPI (have you considered OpenCL)?

Comment: I'm not using cmake.  I've tried to incorporate your solution into tools/build/v2/tools/mpi.jam -- which uses a different syntaxc, but I still can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Using --debug-configuration, it appears that perhaps jam is picking up *two* different mpi shared libraries, but more investigation is needed.  (Just moved apts, no internet for 48 hrs -- except on phone). I'll post more info Monday night and if you can help me get this working, I'd gladly re-offer a bounty for you.